# Get Conditionally Formated Cells (DupeUnique = xlDuplicate)

Tags: excel, vba

I am highlighting all duplicate cells in my selection using:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Now I don't just want to highlight those cells, but I want to get an array with all the effected cells. I tried looping through my selection and checking the Interior property, but that takes ages. I'm looking for something way faster.

Comment: Use arrays: grab your range in an array, then use the array to identify and remove duplicates. Once done, copy the array back to your range. Much faster to work with arrays then a range in excel

Comment: "I tried looping through my selection and checking the Interior property, but that takes ages." - can you post the code for this as well?

Comment: @Zac This works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A function, returning a list (Collection) of all the values in the Excel Selection, corresponding to this condition:

`If myCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = myColor Then`

would be quite useful:

```
Sub TestMe()

    '...OP Code
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Dim unique As Collection
    Set unique = ResultList(Selection)
    If unique.Count > 1 Then Debug.Print unique.Item(2)

End Sub

Public Function ResultList(selectedRange As Range, _
            Optional myColor As Long = 13551615) As Collection

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myResultList As New Collection

    For Each myCell In selectedRange
        If myCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = myColor Then
            myResultList.Add myCell.Value2
        End If
    Next myCell
    Set ResultList = myResultList

End Function
```

Thus, the `Selection` is avoided and one can use it further.